# Magento 2 : How to create custom Newsletter Thank you page?

Tags: module, magento-2.1, newsletter

I want to show custom thank you page after hitting the newsletter subscription button. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom CMS Thank you page in admin after that override newsletter controller and redirect your controller to custom Thank you page.

Comment: Thanks BornCoder! Actually I did that but It wont work. I don't the reason why it does not work in my end.

Comment: did you checked your controller is working or not after override ? and after adding redirect code in your controller , add exit or die() otherwise it will not display cms page to you.

Comment: I have no idea. I did not check it. can you give me a step by step instruction code in here. if you have time. thanks

Comment: $this->_redirect('enewsletter'); like that one I added it. but still it wont work

Comment: place exit after redirect and try and also check that it is coming till before redirect or not

Comment: Can you show me the file structure for overriding a controller in magento 2? Thanks

Comment: Follow this for override : http://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento-2/